Spring Boot の @GetMapping でクエリパラメータのあるリクエストと無いリクエスト
Spring Bootを使い、REST APIを２つ作ろうとしています。
コントローラのクラスで以下のコードを用意したのですが、エラーになってしまいます。
コード
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public ResponseEntity<?> hello() {
    ・・・省略
    }
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public ResponseEntity<?> hello(@RequestParam("type") Integer type) {
    ・・・省略
    }
}

エラー
GET [/hello]}: There is already 'helloController ' bean method

後者のメソッドをコメントアウトし実行した場合はエラーは無く
http://localhost:8080/hello が実行できました。
前者のメソッドをコメントアウトし実行した場合もエラーは無く
http://localhost:8080/hello?type=1 が実行できたので、
エラーの言う通り重複しているのが原因とは思いますが
同じエンドポイントでクエリだけありなしのものを定義する場合はどのように実装するのでしょうか？

１番目のメソッドを削除し、２番目のメソッドの引数を任意に変更して（i.e. @RequestParam(required = false)）、メソッドの中で条件分岐する必要があると思います。
ちなみに引数 type を @PathVariable にすれば、@GetMapping("/hello") と @GetMapping("/hello/{type}") を独立したハンドラーとして定義できます。

@RequestParam(required = false)を試してみました。
受信できることを確認できました。ありがとうございます。
